# How is storage data location in Solidity library public functions

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

While `storage` data location is forbidden in **public functions** in smart contracts it is allowed for library's public functions.

> It seems to work **passing the reference**, which is not well-documented. An example would be the code below:

Where it works and changes `data` variable,  so it has to be **called externally** by the docs.

```sol
library ExampleLib {
    function changeStateVar(uint256[] storage stateVar) public {
        data.push(3);
    }
}

contract ExampleContract {
    ...
    uint256[] public data;
    ...
    function libCallingFunction() public {
        ExampleLib.changeStateVar(data);
    }
    ...
}
```

> How does it work, does it still work with `DELEGATECALL`?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed if you call the function of a library that potentially modifies the state then what is issued is a `delegatecall`.
Libraries are '*stateless and do not have storage*', which is why only `constant` are allowed.
They can only be called directly if the function doesn't modify the state (`view` or `pure`).

Here is a nice ressource explaining pretty much everything about libraries inner workings:
https://jeancvllr.medium.com/solidity-tutorial-all-about-libraries-762e5a3692f9

==> Nice add up, libraries **can actually have state variables** and a 'storage' (well NO they're just using the calling contract's storage at a specific memory slot)!! .

Here is how:
https://dev.to/mudgen/solidity-libraries-can-t-have-state-variables-oh-yes-they-can-3ke9

Big up to Mudgen the creator of the diamond standard eip2535 and the diamond storage pattern.